# Get a record for each parameter without repeating them

Tags: mysql, performance

Is it possible to create a query, preferably without using hundreds of unions, that brings me a record for each item in my where remotely?

For example, assuming I have the following table

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 5 | 14 |
| 6 | 20 |
| 7 | 21 |

And I wanted to get a random record where its value is between 9 and 10, in the same query I also want a random value where its value is between 9 and 11 and then one more where its value is between 10 and 15

In this case it is not enough just to launch:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (value >= 9 AND value <= 10) OR (value >= 9 AND value <= 11) OR (value >= 10 AND value <= 15)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

Because the received values ​​would be from id `1, 2 3`, but without satisfying the condition of `(value >= 10 AND value <= 15)`.

It would be possible to do it with a union, but how to make sure that within each subquery it does not repeat the values ​​already coming from the other subqueries?

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ... WHERE value >= 9 AND value <= 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT ... WHERE value >= 9 AND value <= 11 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT ... WHERE value value >= 10 AND value <= 15 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) tb
```

In this case it would repeat the id `1` twice and could bring any one of the ids `(1, 3, 5 and 4)`

But what I really wanted would be 3 records that satisfy each condition but that are not repeatable and that are random between samples

Comment: The question isn't clear -- do you want to allow repetition of the same row or not?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any easy way in SQL to ensure that each subquery in the union returns a different row.  This is a complex constraint-satisfaction problem that may need dynamic programming to solve it.

Comment: I don't think it is solvable in the general case.  The data provided happens ro work.  But consider a 4th condition of the range of 9-9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using CTEs as follows :

```
with cte1 as (
  select *
  from mytable where value between 9 and 10
  order by RAND() LIMIT 1
),
cte2 as (
  select t.*
  from mytable t
  left join cte1 c1 on c1.id = t.id
  where c1.id is null and t.value between 9 and 11
  order by RAND() LIMIT 1
),
cte3 as (
  select t.*
  from mytable t
  left join cte1 c1 on c1.id = t.id
  left join cte2 c2 on c2.id = t.id
  where c1.id is null and c2.id is null and t.value between 10 and 15
  order by RAND() LIMIT 1
)
select * from cte1 union all
select * from cte2 union all
select * from cte3
```

The first `cte1` was used to obtain the first random row.

`cte2` was used to get the second random row with the condition that it had not already been picked by cte1 using `left join` with the condition `cte1.id is null`.

`cte3` is used to get the third random row that has not already been chosen by `cte1` and `cte2`.

Then we use union all.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CZaQIryi)

Comment: Might this fail to get 3 rows?  Maybe not for this dataset and this ordering of Unions.

Comment: Not sure, could you provide a use case ?

Comment: Simple case:  Each of the 3 queries wants a number between 9 and 10.  There won't be 3 _different_  values.

Comment: Agreed, but with separate ids, which is what the OP wants